# Problem on setup Linux Router

Tags: linux, router

I have tried to make Linux(Ubuntu) as a router but it gets failed. My objective is to create a Linux router then have to share two broadband connection.So How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Docs at lartc.org [contain this use case](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer:
Look for a tutorial.

The short answer:

```
echo -n "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This question is probably better off next door at http://www.serverfault.com/.